# How do I remove/extract string from column variables in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data table with this column

```
pay range

â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦40,000 and above
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦21,000 - â‚¦30,000
â‚¦11,000 - â‚¦20,000
â‚¦11,000 - â‚¦20,000
â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000
â‚¦11,000 - â‚¦20,000
```

i want to remove certain characters in the string. Like So:
old = â‚¦11,000 - â‚¦20,000     new = 11,000 - 20,000

How do I go about this ? thank you

Comment: apologies if the table is formatted wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a data frame only with 3 rows, but will work the same.
Your data components might also have class 'factor', so you should change that into character class as below, so to be able to use gsub.
gsub functions as changing the former one with the next one you puts in.

```
payrange <- data.frame(c("â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000","â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000","â‚¦5,000 - â‚¦10,000"))
colnames(payrange) <- "range"

payrange$range <- as.character(payrange$range)

for (row in 1:dim(payrange)[1]){
payrange[row,] <- gsub("[â‚|]","",payrange[row,])}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. changing the data components from class factor to a character class to use gsub. Is that the only reason?

Comment: gsub only can be used on 'words', like character or numeric... and so on. If your data has class of 'factor', gsub can't accept them cause they are not 'words'. So you should check the class first, and then decide what to do. So yes, that's why I changed into character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions and the `stringr` package to do stuff like this pretty easily.  I can't reproduce the characters in the table you pasted, but this should give you the idea.

```
> df <- data.frame(pay_range = c("$5,000 - $10,000", "$21,000 - $30,000"))
> df %>% mutate(pay_range2 = str_replace_all(pay_range, "\\$", ""))
          pay_range      pay_range2
1  $5,000 - $10,000  5,000 - 10,000
2 $21,000 - $30,000 21,000 - 30,000
```

Note that the slashes in `"\\$"` are there because `$` is understood as a special character in regex.  Type in `?stringi`, then hit the link `stringi-search-regex` to see what other characters are treated specially.